# Se me duplica el último registrado insertado en un foreach php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, while, foreach

En un sistema de compartir archivos, donde un usuario sube y puede compartir sus archivos subidos con otro usuario, tengo un problema. La subida de archivos, todo correcta, pero al compartir archivos, al listar esos archivos compartidos, me sale el ultimo archivo compartido, duplicado tantas veces como archivos le hayan compartido a ese usuario. Por ejemplo si usuario X sube 3 archivos, y se los comparte al usuario Y, al usuario Y le saldran 3 archivos compartidos, pero le saldrán 3 archivos compartidos que seran los 3 el ultimo archivo que el usuario X le haya compartido.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"><!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <section class="content-header"><!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <h1><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Archivos Compartidos Conmigo</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Compartidos conmigo</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content"><!-- Main content -->
        <div class="row"><!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php
                $user=$_SESSION["user_id"];
               // $inv=$_SESSION['inv'];
                $files = mysqli_query($con,"select * from permision where user_id=$user");
              //echo $user;


                $count = mysqli_num_rows($files);
              //  echo $count;
                         while(  $r=mysqli_fetch_array($files)){
                    $id=$r['id'];
                    echo $id;
                  }



            ?>
                <?php if($count>0):?>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header"></div> <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Archivos</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                </tr>


                                <?php 

                                foreach($files as $fx){



                           //       echo $id;
                                        $fx = mysqli_query($con,"select * from permision where id=$id");
                              echo $id;





                                    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($fx)) {

                                        $file_id=$rows['file_id'];
                                //   echo $file_id;
                                      $file=mysqli_query($con,"select * from file where id=$file_id");

                                    }




                                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($file)) {
                                        $file_is_folder=$row['is_folder'];
                                        $file_filename=$row['filename'];
                                        $file_code=$row['code'];
                                        $file_description=$row['description'];
                                        $file_created_at=$row['created_at'];
                                   }
                                   //echo var_dump($file);
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>    
                                        <?php if($file_is_folder):?>
                                        <a href="myfiles.php?folder=<?php echo $file_code;?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                        <a href="file.php?code=<?php echo $file_code;?>">
```

Hay más codigo, pero creo que el fallo está ahí.

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Buenas una duda, la tabla permision que representa?

Comment: La tabla permision representa todos los permisos otorgados. Tengo 3 tablas. Una users donde estan los usuarios registrados, otra files donde estan todos los archivos subidos por todos los usuarios, y luego la permision donde estan todos los permisos dados de cada archivo a cada usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te diré las cosas que pienso que están mal y tu me vas corrigiendo si no es así.

1) Entiendo que con esta consulta obtienes el permiso que ha dado el usuario, pero que ocurre si el usuario ha dado permiso de otros dos archivos a otro usuario los trae también?

```
$files = mysqli_query($con,"select * from permision where user_id=$user");
```

2) Segundo error. Este bucle recorre todos los permisos que ha dado el usuario por fichero, entiendo que hará 3 iteraciones, ya que el usuario ha concedido 3 ficheros. El problema viene con la variable $id ya que esta se queda con el id del ultimo fichero.

```
          while(  $r=mysqli_fetch_array($files)){
            $id=$r['id'];
            echo $id;
          }
```

3)En esta parte vuelves a cometer el error anterior.

```
                       while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($fx)) {
                                $file_id=$rows['file_id'];
                        //   echo $file_id;
                              $file=mysqli_query($con,"select * from file where id=$file_id");

                            }

                            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($file)) {
                                $file_is_folder=$row['is_folder'];
                                $file_filename=$row['filename'];
                                $file_code=$row['code'];
                                $file_description=$row['description'];
                                $file_created_at=$row['created_at'];
                           }
```

Solución:
Yo creo que tendría que quedar así obviamente se puede mejorar. Espero que te sirva.

```
<div class="content-wrapper"><!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <section class="content-header"><!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <h1><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Archivos Compartidos Conmigo</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Compartidos conmigo</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content"><!-- Main content -->
        <div class="row"><!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php
                $user=$_SESSION["user_id"];
               // $inv=$_SESSION['inv'];
                $files = mysqli_query($con,"select * from permision where user_id=$user");
              //echo $user;

                $count = mysqli_num_rows($files);
            ?>
                <?php if($count>0):?>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header"></div> <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Archivos</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                </tr>


                                <?php 

                                while(  $r=mysqli_fetch_array($files)){                         
                                    $file_id = $r["file_id"]
                                    $file=mysqli_query($con,"select * from file where id=$file_id");
                                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($file)) {
                                        $file_is_folder=$row['is_folder'];
                                        $file_filename=$row['filename'];
                                        $file_code=$row['code'];
                                        $file_description=$row['description'];
                                        $file_created_at=$row['created_at'];                                            
                                    }                                   
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>    
                                        <?php if($file_is_folder):?>
                                        <a href="myfiles.php?folder=<?php echo $file_code;?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                        <a href="file.php?code=<?php echo $file_code;?>">

                                <?php
                                }                               
                                ?>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes la razón en todo. Yo creo que es eso, que se queda con la variable $id del ultimo fichero. Cual seria la manera de solucionarlo? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: He editado con el código que creo que te tendría que servir, puedes ver que he eliminado while innecesarios y llamadas a BBDD innecesarias, espero que solucione tu problema.

Comment: Primero, gracias de nuevo. Lo he probado y ahora solo me muestra un registro (el ultimo que he compartido). A que se debe?

Comment: Se debe a que los <tr> <td> deben estar dentro del primer While.

Comment: Solucionado!! Muchas gracias de verdad!! Disculpa las molestias!!

Comment: Ya sabes si te sirvio ponlo como respuesta por si le sirve a alguien más

Comment: No se si se hace así. Creo que sí. Espero que le sirva a más gente.

Comment: No se hace así xD tienes que marcar cual es la respuesta de las que te han dado como solucion debe  estar al lado

Comment: Ya lo he visto. Disculpa la ignorancia. Ya está marcada xD.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una instruccion DISTINCT en la ultima consulta, de esta forma

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM file WHERE id=$file_id
```

Estaría bien conocer la estructura de las tablas que llamas para tener una idea más clara

Como consejo hay algunas cosas que podrian ser optimizadas en el código, yo creo que seria una buena idea utilizar JOIN de mysql de esa forma, podrias haber hecho el codigo más eficiente y en menos líneas de código y quizas solo necesitarias realizar 1 consulta.

Saludos, espero te sea de utilidad esta información.

Comment: He hecho esta consulta y nada. Sigue igual. Aqui te paso imagenes con las estructuras de tablas. File, permision y user, en ese orden. https://gyazo.com/a5bab33f8eea815e35699426770fb4d1     https://gyazo.com/98a83fed104c341bf4e9187cdc1a0052  https://gyazo.com/685170784489dc55216f795457caa779    Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de AnonimoPer que me ha servido:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"><!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<section class="content-header"><!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <h1><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Archivos Compartidos Conmigo</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Compartidos conmigo</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section class="content"><!-- Main content -->
    <div class="row"><!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <?php
            $user=$_SESSION["user_id"];
           // $inv=$_SESSION['inv'];
            $files = mysqli_query($con,"select * from permision where user_id=$user");
          //echo $user;

            $count = mysqli_num_rows($files);
        ?>
            <?php if($count>0):?>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header"></div> <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Archivos</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Eliminar</th>
                            </tr>


                            <?php 

                            while(  $r=mysqli_fetch_array($files)){                         
                                $file_id = $r["file_id"]
                                $file=mysqli_query($con,"select * from file where id=$file_id");
                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($file)) {
                                    $file_is_folder=$row['is_folder'];
                                    $file_filename=$row['filename'];
                                    $file_code=$row['code'];
                                    $file_description=$row['description'];
                                    $file_created_at=$row['created_at'];                                            
                                }                                   
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>    
                                    <?php if($file_is_folder):?>
                                    <a href="myfiles.php?folder=<?php echo $file_code;?>">
                                        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                    <a href="file.php?code=<?php echo $file_code;?>">

                            <?php
                            }                               
                            ?>
```